# Abour ResourceBundle in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, localization, flex4, resourcebundle

I creadet a class that has more ResourceBundles in it. My app is multilanguage so I will need many ".properties" files.

here is a sample code

```
[ResourceBundle("LocalizedStrings_en_US")]
[ResourceBundle("LocalizedStrings_fr_FR")]
...
public class LocaleLoader
{
...
}
```

My question is if I add many ResourceBunlde lines in this class, will the file size of the main swf increase drastically or not?

Should use separata class files to load separate ResourceBundles for each language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[ResourceBundle]` annotation itself won't have any effect on the file size. It's the `-locale` compile option of the **mxmlc** that matters.

`-locale=en_US` means to embed only the US-locale in the SWF

`-locale=en_US, ja_JP` means to embed both the US-locale and the Japan-locale

If you don't embed the Japan-locale you can load it at runtime with `resourceManager.loadResourceModule(...)`.

To address completely the topic of Flex Localization Support please refer to the [Slides & Samples in the Flex Localization Support](http://training.obecto.com/2009/04/flex-3-localization-support/) article I wrote in the [Obecto Training Portal](http://training.obecto.com/).